# Accessing certain column of attribute table of shapefile and renaming it using GeoPandas?

Tags: python, r, geopandas, rgdal

Currently, I am working on converting some R code into python for someone. This person is taking the shapefile and removing all columns except for a select few and renaming them:

```
ec <- readOGR(".", file) #read a file #identify column
ec.dt<-data.table::as.data.table(ec) #check to see 
ec<-ec[,c(5,7,4)] #get the desired columns
names(ec@data)[1] <- "ecs"
names(ec@data)[2] <- "ecd"
names(ec@data)[3] <- "elevation"
```

and below is my attempt at getting converting the code using geopandas with python:

```
ec = gpd.read_file(x) # ec 0 <- readOGR(".", file)

for i in range(1, ec.length()): # I'm using 1 here so I don't get the title column out
if (i != 4 | i != 5 | i != 7):
    ec.drop([ec[i]], axis = 1)

#getting the columns of the ec shapefiles and trying to rename them
ec = ec.rename(columns = {ec[1] : 'ecs'}).set_geometry('ecs')
ec = ec.rename(columns = ({ec[2] : 'ecd'}).set_geometry('ecd')
ec = ec.rename(columns = ({ec[3] : 'elevation'}).set_geometry('elevation')
```

I know I am misusing the rename function, but the main thing I'm concerned about is how I access columns, and How I remove other columns from the attribute table of the shapefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you've never used `pandas` before I'd very strongly recommend reading about [indexing and selecting data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html). Indexing columns will be how you subset your dataframe.

To get you started, your example can be re-written as:

```
ec = gpd.read_file(x)

title_col = ec.columns[0]
name_map = dict(zip(ec.columns[[5, 7, 4]], ['ecs', 'ecd', 'elevation']))
ec.rename(columns=name_map, inplace=True)

ec[[title_col, 'ecs', 'ecd', 'elevation', 'geometry']].to_file('output.shp')
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply but when making the name_map, why do you use two index brackets when you do `ec.columns[[5, 7, 4]]` ?

Comment: All good @AmmarHoque - it's not technically a double index, under the hood I'm building a list of column indexes `[5, 7, 4]` and that list is used to index those values - it's about the order the operations are  completed in. You could write `name_map = {ec.columns[5] : 'ecs', ec.columns[7]: 'ecd', ec.columns[4]: 'elevation'}` if its easier to understand.